# foreign key constraint field set to NULL not working

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I want to allow NULL values to a field with foreign key constraint set.

Here's the table schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE `internal_team_head` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `internal_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` enum('lead','project_manager') NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`internal_team_id`,`users_id`,`type`),
  KEY `fk_internal_team_has_users_users1_idx` (`users_id`),
  KEY `fk_internal_team_has_users_internal_team1_idx` (`internal_team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_internal_team_has_users_internal_team1` FOREIGN KEY (`internal_team_id`) REFERENCES `internal_team` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I want to change `users_id` to allow NULL values and default to NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE `internal_team_head` CHANGE `users_id` `users_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

The Alter query executes successfully but `users_id` `Null` attribute is still set to `No` and default value set to `0`.

How do I enforce the changes?

Comment: You want a foreign key which only works some of the time?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes.. when the field is not set, I simply want it to have NULL value.

Comment: Can you please also provide `users` table script and some sample data for both the tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping foreign key constraint first, then running your alter statement should work. You can add the constraint back again after that.